# Merging 2 sf objects leads to significant loss of information

Tags: r, merge, r-sf

I have 2 `sf` objects one which is bigger and contains all the info I need to display and one smaller with some other data. I want to merge them so I do it by the code below using the common info columns `ac_code` `AC_NO` but then I see 2 things. First that I lose sigificant info from ny big file around 1000 rows and secondly that I now have a `geometry.x` and `geometry.y` column with not the same coords at the same row so I wonder how could I fix that and keep all the info and also merge the datasets. I give a sample of the objects

```
# Convert sf objects to data frames
dfdatatabad <- as.data.frame(databad)
dfAC <- as.data.frame(AC)

# Perform the merge based on the common columns
merged_df <- merge(dfdatatabad, dfAC, by.x = " ", by.y = "AC_NO")

# Convert the merged data frame back to an sf object
merged_sf <- st_as_sf(merged_df)
```

databad

```
databad<-structure(list(ac_code = c(259L, 259L, 259L), booth_no = 1:3, 
    state = c("West Bengal", "West Bengal", "West Bengal"), ac_name = c("Khandaghosh", 
    "Khandaghosh", "Khandaghosh"), voteshare.IND = c(0.01, 0, 
    0.01), voteshare.BMUP = c(0.01, 0, 0), voteshare.CPM = c(0.58, 
    0.31, 0.25), voteshare.AITC = c(0.33, 0.52, 0.57), voteshare.BJP = c(0.06, 
    0.13, 0.11), voteshare.INC = c(0, 0.02, 0.05), voteshare.BSP = c(0, 
    0, 0.01), voteshare.SUCI = c(0, 0.01, 0.01), nn_hospital = c("Khundkuri Hospital", 
    "Khundkuri Hospital", "Mankar Rural Hospital"), distance_nn_hospital = c(8949.68646563084, 
    17217.1419457099, 16939.2318150416), nn_school = c("বর্ধমান টাউন স্কুল", 
    "বর্ধমান টাউন স্কুল", "Guskara Girls High School"
    ), distance_nn_school = c(16834.9368635036, 24332.8584456302, 
    19846.4525464748), nn_bank = c("contai", "contai", "Allahabad Bank"
    ), distance_nn_bank = c(13959.9950089655, 20598.4763042432, 
    19688.6296071566), nn_atm = c("ING Bank", "ING Bank", "ING Bank"
    ), distance_nn_atm = c(55404.6817200836, 47524.5016641311, 
    45106.1556369373), voteshare.JMM = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), voteshare.JDP = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), voteshare.CPI.ML..L. = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), 
    voteshare.IUML = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), voteshare.GaAP = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), voteshare.NOTA = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), geometry = structure(list(structure(list(list(
        structure(c(87.7090902547602, 87.7151753707173, 87.7154550055682, 
        87.7086421531382, 87.7023431042605, 87.6970612820198, 
        87.7017218525372, 87.7090902547602, 23.2040982701717, 
        23.2136143676662, 23.2156954885727, 23.2276541162583, 
        23.2281630737782, 23.2181646062169, 23.2053620549479, 
        23.2040982701717), dim = c(8L, 2L)))), class = c("XY", 
    "MULTIPOLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(list(structure(c(87.6365062737229, 
    87.6376152918208, 87.6308791550368, 87.625023101282, 87.62345364621, 
    87.6365062737229, 23.2401534236987, 23.244460158139, 23.2496234950258, 
    23.2489032619139, 23.2468180156553, 23.2401534236987), dim = c(6L, 
    2L)))), class = c("XY", "MULTIPOLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
        list(structure(c(87.6586184806029, 87.67258178803, 87.6804334223628, 
        87.6655208748092, 87.6611300171367, 87.6604474038247, 
        87.6586184806029, 23.3194136362408, 23.3169136956011, 
        23.3271416599132, 23.333645873538, 23.3347376687085, 
        23.3208934817488, 23.3194136362408), dim = c(7L, 2L)))), class = c("XY", 
    "MULTIPOLYGON", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_MULTIPOLYGON", "sfc"
    ), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 87.62345364621, 
    ymin = 23.2040982701717, xmax = 87.7154550055682, ymax = 23.3347376687085
    ), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(input = "WGS 84", 
        wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n    DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic latitude (Lat)\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic longitude (Lon)\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4326]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(ac_code = NA_integer_, 
booth_no = NA_integer_, state = NA_integer_, ac_name = NA_integer_, 
voteshare.IND = NA_integer_, voteshare.BMUP = NA_integer_, voteshare.CPM = NA_integer_, 
voteshare.AITC = NA_integer_, voteshare.BJP = NA_integer_, voteshare.INC = NA_integer_, 
voteshare.BSP = NA_integer_, voteshare.SUCI = NA_integer_, nn_hospital = NA_integer_, 
distance_nn_hospital = NA_integer_, nn_school = NA_integer_, 
distance_nn_school = NA_integer_, nn_bank = NA_integer_, distance_nn_bank = NA_integer_, 
nn_atm = NA_integer_, distance_nn_atm = NA_integer_, voteshare.JMM = NA_integer_, 
voteshare.JDP = NA_integer_, voteshare.CPI.ML..L. = NA_integer_, 
voteshare.IUML = NA_integer_, voteshare.GaAP = NA_integer_, voteshare.NOTA = NA_integer_
), levels = c("constant", "aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"), row.names = c(NA, 
3L), class = c("sf", "data.frame"))
```

AC

```
AC<-structure(list(OBJECTID = c(39L, 39L, 38L), ST_CODE = c(19, 19, 
19), ST_NAME = c("WEST BENGAL", "WEST BENGAL", "WEST BENGAL"), 
    DT_CODE = c(9, 9, 9), DIST_NAME = c("BARDDHAMAN", "BARDDHAMAN", 
    "BARDDHAMAN"), AC_NO = c(260, 263, 265), AC_NAME = c("Bardhaman Dakshin", 
    "Monteswar", "Memari"), PC_NO = c(39, 39, 38), PC_NAME = c("BARDHAMAN-DURGAPUR", 
    "BARDHAMAN-DURGAPUR", "BARDHAMAN PURBA(SC)"), PC_ID = c(1939, 
    1939, 1938), STATUS = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), Shape_Leng = c(0.19971905621, 1.26546655596, 0.9227426759
    ), Shape_Area = c(0.00211715942, 0.03266718852, 0.02052033661
    ), geometry = structure(list(structure(list(list(structure(c(87.8787711009056, 
    87.9020513659778, 87.8981379256248, 87.8852487296452, 87.8821239740422, 
    87.8693263290469, 87.8598580489099, 87.8485280642188, 87.8240021400867, 
    87.8212105482283, 87.8246764652467, 87.8409353247055, 87.8787711009056, 
    23.2630741788303, 23.251022247179, 23.2442217420398, 23.2399405671035, 
    23.222826128623, 23.2190496406284, 23.2190494553681, 23.2319402539396, 
    23.2407004420718, 23.244862350717, 23.2522611028676, 23.2583010792314, 
    23.2630741788303), dim = c(13L, 2L)))), class = c("XY", "MULTIPOLYGON", 
    "sfg")), structure(list(list(structure(c(88.1447694640396, 
    88.1415242055777, 88.1463020877712, 88.1269341604832, 88.1282794914055, 
    88.1324241465572, 88.1380241529923, 88.1527172558967, 88.154647084995, 
    88.1624853502188, 88.1593397096599, 88.1832571623882, 88.1891840364142, 
    88.1860221136297, 88.1889489698191, 88.197951743778, 88.2283150539966, 
    88.2214600301563, 88.232679427014, 88.2174132455249, 88.2110411684152, 
    88.2146294013259, 88.212412060768, 88.2067214800123, 88.2170764287342, 
    88.2042364085834, 88.2033104081489, 88.2082871385407, 88.2023296497936, 
    88.2168977613227, 88.2058793980158, 88.2211077081542, 88.215238379048, 
    88.2076125381881, 88.1891397708838, 88.193082485968, 88.1872799809864, 
    88.1808660611199, 88.1805227278417, 88.1728327554274, 88.1712344712939, 
    88.1660353322648, 88.1682761999867, 88.1600918999213, 88.1574300928246, 
    88.1501566243288, 88.1526895127109, 88.1483039022034, 88.1392762143259, 
    88.1252969303092, 88.1184832420081, 88.1193612609135, 88.0914921106724, 
    88.066052834171, 88.0603342233458, 88.0408622597855, 88.0375414034131, 
    88.0357180576423, 88.0435709800168, 88.0490466344946, 88.0682137044989, 
    88.0726201666874, 88.0829827083853, 88.0857459545123, 88.0824730257096, 
    88.0784397372042, 88.0674552360704, 88.0682409800373, 88.058033196375, 
    88.0512722542112, 88.0539486465129, 88.0644418390197, 88.0533302133188, 
    88.0559191834236, 88.0488818445216, 88.0329459082271, 88.0287576143725, 
    88.0226485925585, 88.0150309715022, 88.0131048655971, 87.9950707803923, 
    87.9956950205088, 87.9928305161155, 87.9971758298008, 88.0363064094133, 
    88.0344732124688, 88.0429786163701, 88.0488586590999, 88.0560090077096, 
    88.0530418142284, 88.028922416936, 88.0355218030888, 88.049929436894, 
    88.0557169240968, 88.0588723870511, 88.0640983672459, 88.0779472540626, 
    88.0817918684, 88.0983846083631, 88.1029608652518, 88.0996493591307, 
    88.1064564769849, 88.1032486402127, 88.1142864657479, 88.1144054505511, 
    88.117986255961, 88.1199855235132, 88.1438579921527, 88.1447694640396, 
    23.4795340696417, 23.4788950419726, 23.4547038985661, 23.4391593517228, 
    23.4352802906529, 23.4382268312033, 23.4291602935128, 23.428001731095, 
    23.4212991594287, 23.4215150884506, 23.4171556958787, 23.4180386781425, 
    23.4156623131653, 23.4133894763433, 23.4106231626289, 23.409038745142, 
    23.41268280167, 23.402231320619, 23.3918095369806, 23.3817336191113, 
    23.3718289600385, 23.350875016269, 23.328293444387, 23.3186467243669, 
    23.305456772612, 23.2996154376024, 23.2930168068802, 23.2920261388953, 
    23.285948029478, 23.2812667596533, 23.2711598862198, 23.2565935472545, 
    23.2521830039425, 23.2561046245289, 23.255613969709, 23.2416812417959, 
    23.2361240700698, 23.2367899272134, 23.2330271943496, 23.2333343173249, 
    23.2273942133723, 23.2290632867413, 23.237569694286, 23.2401335822991, 
    23.2465870201749, 23.2458576672976, 23.2501150227901, 23.2544050722364, 
    23.2518633974778, 23.2575389676493, 23.2534968936667, 23.2491020812961, 
    23.2502670217057, 23.2583048680752, 23.2735509434214, 23.2711165281053, 
    23.2778034254877, 23.2989747866571, 23.2964009890145, 23.2862712970827, 
    23.2873574397941, 23.2912880140307, 23.2894370446839, 23.3104792434224, 
    23.3165638864143, 23.3094872714205, 23.3138165753747, 23.3196402351088, 
    23.3225116175172, 23.3196279755507, 23.3308651879781, 23.3337754723602, 
    23.3533255150605, 23.367434930078, 23.3603776702933, 23.3567046591927, 
    23.362609942295, 23.359660026589, 23.3574859730992, 23.3629997210603, 
    23.3602971863661, 23.3567334896589, 23.3594497453096, 23.3709240819808, 
    23.3925766613839, 23.4065871239966, 23.4083472950916, 23.4243910565021, 
    23.4264600296067, 23.4316953600529, 23.4414866415953, 23.4550646939805, 
    23.4601441656208, 23.4526011550194, 23.4622618442088, 23.4643654277224, 
    23.4626348614098, 23.4559815429139, 23.4554761688901, 23.4629847642356, 
    23.4649628158813, 23.4665179019797, 23.4695333944507, 23.4684672238834, 
    23.4737529829139, 23.4701208963623, 23.4786217433988, 23.4832368294162, 
    23.4795340696417), dim = c(109L, 2L)))), class = c("XY", 
    "MULTIPOLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(list(structure(c(88.0368297159187, 
    88.0375414034131, 88.0408622597855, 88.0603342233458, 88.066052834171, 
    88.0914921106724, 88.1193612609135, 88.1184832420081, 88.1252969303092, 
    88.1392762143259, 88.1483039022034, 88.1526895127109, 88.1501566243288, 
    88.1574300928246, 88.1600918999213, 88.1682761999867, 88.1660353322648, 
    88.1712344712939, 88.1728327554274, 88.1805227278417, 88.1808660611199, 
    88.1872799809864, 88.193082485968, 88.1891397708838, 88.2076125381881, 
    88.215238379048, 88.2211077081542, 88.2356641213022, 88.2305852594022, 
    88.2150682318135, 88.2138689552881, 88.2057821183502, 88.2012931316727, 
    88.1890298620386, 88.192661448567, 88.1857006050989, 88.1861530144501, 
    88.1786117116612, 88.168678701461, 88.1644300523051, 88.1540229303141, 
    88.1532592979783, 88.1627775984075, 88.1579451102787, 88.1505863815563, 
    88.1282960695081, 88.1077682901745, 88.1006227943066, 88.0979371183034, 
    88.070154867753, 88.0653592536267, 88.0498479421289, 88.0274010059517, 
    88.0051225406727, 88.0092594247827, 88.0029795515651, 87.9950259419937, 
    87.9899214485161, 87.9859815950746, 87.9907846438962, 87.9851718023369, 
    87.9820310909622, 87.9861686135907, 87.9988666029114, 88.0070658056425, 
    88.0142194502675, 88.0223084599675, 88.0424631393624, 88.0478566398721, 
    88.0516016650848, 88.0391052354183, 88.0378916030151, 88.0335765605099, 
    88.0372707308596, 88.0296005462283, 88.0292682107594, 88.0368297159187, 
    23.2779998167382, 23.2778034254877, 23.2711165281053, 23.2735509434214, 
    23.2583048680752, 23.2502670217057, 23.2491020812961, 23.2534968936667, 
    23.2575389676493, 23.2518633974778, 23.2544050722364, 23.2501150227901, 
    23.2458576672976, 23.2465870201749, 23.2401335822991, 23.237569694286, 
    23.2290632867413, 23.2273942133723, 23.2333343173249, 23.2330271943496, 
    23.2367899272134, 23.2361240700698, 23.2416812417959, 23.255613969709, 
    23.2561046245289, 23.2521830039425, 23.2565935472545, 23.2601763050924, 
    23.2476044564805, 23.2421502220552, 23.2365674924959, 23.2192556285445, 
    23.1854368541275, 23.1881569318969, 23.1750087995165, 23.1693997450023, 
    23.1599893200511, 23.1544127922166, 23.1566127812549, 23.1417751914719, 
    23.1340876832001, 23.1259432527789, 23.1265006795628, 23.1029169085885, 
    23.1026913703105, 23.1215422135024, 23.1287588880123, 23.1334831832024, 
    23.1440700940597, 23.1528690744483, 23.1613942463474, 23.1533707315741, 
    23.1637837576144, 23.1637168534501, 23.1674476172138, 23.1774969313383, 
    23.180720273322, 23.1770294763293, 23.1824538307797, 23.1922094937732, 
    23.1978493707519, 23.2089632825295, 23.2168098287107, 23.2133818630826, 
    23.2026395853487, 23.2005831631825, 23.2109870044467, 23.2091083197932, 
    23.2162744847797, 23.2264714163229, 23.2420317327783, 23.2564438865762, 
    23.2573382821361, 23.2608509764914, 23.2636108402681, 23.2768313581807, 
    23.2779998167382), dim = c(77L, 2L)))), class = c("XY", "MULTIPOLYGON", 
    "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_MULTIPOLYGON", "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 87.8212105482283, 
    ymin = 23.1026913703105, xmax = 88.2356641213022, ymax = 23.4832368294162
    ), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(input = "WGS 84", 
        wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n    DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic latitude (Lat)\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic longitude (Lon)\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4326]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(OBJECTID = NA_integer_, 
ST_CODE = NA_integer_, ST_NAME = NA_integer_, DT_CODE = NA_integer_, 
DIST_NAME = NA_integer_, AC_NO = NA_integer_, AC_NAME = NA_integer_, 
PC_NO = NA_integer_, PC_NAME = NA_integer_, PC_ID = NA_integer_, 
STATUS = NA_integer_, Shape_Leng = NA_integer_, Shape_Area = NA_integer_
), levels = c("constant", "aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"), row.names = c(2L, 
5L, 7L), class = c("sf", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you consider `dplyr::left_join()` if you are concerned about losing data; it will keep all information on the left hand side and add only those from the right that match (and NAs when no match was found).

The two `geometry` columns is a somewhat separate problem: your `{sf}` data frame is allowed to have only 1 active geometry column at a time. Which is why calling a `dplyr::*_join` on two sf objects will fail - you need to get rid of one of the geometries by calling `sf::st_drop_geometry()` first.

The best approach usually is starting with the bigger dataset and left joining to it the smaller one, stripped of geometry so that no confusion occurs about which geometry should win (and which to lose).

```
merged <- AC %>% 
  dplyr::left_join(st_drop_geometry(databad), by = c("AC_NO" = "ac_code"))
```

Note that this will result in a dataset of 39 variables, which is 2 less than  the total (27 + 14). This due to the fact that one geometry column was droped, and the AC code used for joining is not duplicated / and 27 + 14 - 2 = 39